# Java inheriting public class with default constructor

Tags: java

I am just inheriting class ConstructorTwo in class ConstructorOne, not creating any object (explicitly atleast). So why does the constructor in class ConstructorTwo has to be public?

I am getting this error : ConstructorTwo() is not public in ConstructorTwo; cannot be accessed from outside package

```
package one;

import two.ConstructorTwo;

public class ConstructorOne extends ConstructorTwo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    }
}


package two;

public class ConstructorTwo {

    ConstructorTwo() { 
        super(); 
        System.out.println("Default constructor in package TWO!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I presume you're getting a compilation error? It is probably worth including that in your question.

Comment: @khelwood included.

Comment: The error is quiet self explanatory `cannot be accessed from outside package`. Have a look at [Access Modifiers in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: actually it needs to be `protected` or `pulbic` and Eclipse is providing a better error description: "Implicit super constructor ConstructorTwo() is not visible for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor"

Answer (score 2):

The reason that it has to be public is because when Java calls any constructor, it has to call the superclass constructor before it calls any of the code in the subclass's constructor. If Java cannot access the superclass constructor because of privacy errors, then it cannot execute the superclass constructor which is a required operation for calling any constructor (according to Java). This is why it has to be public.

Comment: ConstructorTwo could be called from a class in the same package (e.g. two.MyMain could call ConstructorTwo()).

Comment: Why would java call the constructor of class ConstructorOne in the firstplace  when I have not created any object of class ConstructorOne?

Comment: That is how Java was made. It's not my fault. Think about it. Suppose you are extending JFrame. If the constructor is not called, some crucial initialization processes might not happen. That is why it has to be called.

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor in class `ConstructorOne` calls `super();` which is the default constructor in class `ConstructorTwo` . When calling methods or constructors or accessing fields over package-boundries they need to be public.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thank you very much. I have fixed my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The `ConstructorOne` class has an automatically generated public constructor, which takes no arguments, and calls `super()`. Effectively, this:

```
public ConstructorOne() {
    super();
}
```

All classes implicitly have such a constructor if you don't write a constructor yourself. So there does need to be an available constructor to call in the superclass (in this case, it must be either `public` or `protected` to be accessible by a subclass in another package).

Comment: I understand that but why would it be invoked at all? I have not created any object of class ConstructorOne at all and as far as I know it should not create an object to invoke the static main() method right?

Comment: Doesn't matter if you're not invoking it. It's effectively there, so it has to follow the rules. Code problems in methods that are not being called can still cause compilation problems.

Comment: you are not invoking it but how should the compiler know if that will always be the case - this could be a library or being used somewhere/sometime else.

Answer (score 0):

When a Constructor is public, anyone can call it.  When a constructor is private, it usually means that you need to construct the object in some other manner, usually with another public static method created by the author for that purpose.